# KVM live migration for non shared storage

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, storage, live-migration

I am trying to live migrate my KVM based VM from one host to another for **non shared storage** using virsh migrate.
I have set both the *hostnames at /etc/hosts* on each of the host. Also I have set *passwordless ssh* between the hosts. Still i am not able to live migrate my VM.

Steps I followed:

1. Created a vm on host1 with a lv
2. Created a dummy lv on host2
3. symlink the host2 lv with host1 vm disk
4. executed command:  **virsh migrate --live --persistent --verbose --copy-storage-all --desturi qemu+ssh://root@host2/system v4108**

I get the error :
**error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'drive-mirror': Failed to connect socket: No route to host**

Can anyone help to sort this issue? Is anything that I might be missing out?

Comment: Well, according to your error message, `host1` cannot connect to `host2`. Try pinging  from `host1` to  `host2`. Probably also try to connect to SSH in `host2` from `host1`.

Comment: when i added 49152-49215/tcp to firewall the error wwas gone.. but then now m getting 

**setlocale: No such file or directory
error: operation failed: domain 'v4159' is already defined with uuid 094e0a92-a747-4b7c-9a7c-2df7ad866f65**

Comment: already locale has  
 **LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8**

Comment: to solve the above error i used **putenv("LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8");** during runtime